# C# get a field before it exists

Tags: c#, dynamic, field

In my C# code, I'm dynamically creating a grid with a different number of rows depending on the selection the user made on the previous window. When the loop creates each row, its giving each Textblock in the row a name by appending a unique string to each name. Each row will have a different name so I can later "grab" that field and change the value of that field.

How do I setup my code to look for a field that doesn't yet exist, but when the application runs, the field WILL be there?

Comment: You can't reference a row before it exists. You keep a reference when you create the row by putting it in a list or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dynamically creating controls, rather than the "normal" property created by visual studio. You should keep a reference to the control instance and any other related data, in your own collection.

```cs
public class Row{
    public TextControl Text { get; set; }
    //...
}

public List<Row> Rows = new List<Row>();

var row = new Row{
    Text = new TextControl()
    //...
};
Rows.Add(row);

// etc
```